# Query with multiple ManyToOne joins

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have a model with the following classes:

```
public class Organization  {

    private Person person;

}

public class PersonAddress  {

    private Person person;
    private Address address;

}

public class Address {

    ...

}
```

There's not a direct association between Person and Address, nor Person and PersonAddress, nor Address and PersonAddress. PersonAddress is the ManyToMany association between Person and Address, but we're trying to avoid mapping the corresponding collections because their abusive use may lead to some performance issues.

I'm trying to create a querydsl method passing an organization as a parameter and getting a projected result with the organization, person and address data, but my best attempt so far is giving me a query with a cross join.

Can I build this query in a way that the cross join is avoided? And also avoiding creating the collection associations.

Here is the querydsl query and the generated SQL:

QueryDSL:

```
QOrganization organization = QOrganization.organization;
QPerson person = QPerson.person;
QPerson personOrganization = new QPerson("personOrganization");
QAddressPerson addressPerson = QAddressPerson.addressPerson;
QAddress address = QAddress.address;
QCity city = QCity.city;
JPQLQuery<Organization> query = newQuery().from(addressPerson,organization)
    .join(organization.person, person)//
    .join(addressPerson.address, address)//
    .join(address.city, city)//
    .leftJoin(addressPerson.person, personOrganization);
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    builder.and(organization.eq(organizationParam));
    query.where(builder)//
        .select(create(organization.id, organization.type, //
            QPerson.create(person.id, person.type, //
            QAddressPerson.create(addressPerson.id, //
            QAddress.create(address.id, //
            QCity.create(city.id, city.name), address.zipcode)))));
```

Resulting SQL:

```
select
    organization1_.org_id as col_0_0_,
    organization1_.org_tp as col_1_0_,
    person2_.pes_id as col_4_0_,
    person2_.pes_tp as col_5_0_,
    addresspe0_.enp_id as col_10_0_,
    address3_.end_id as col_11_0_,
    city4_.cid_id as col_12_0_,
    city4_.cid_nm as col_13_0_,
    address3_.END_VR_CEP as col_15_0_
from
    address_person addresspe0_ 
inner join
    address address3_ 
        on addresspe0_.end_id=address3_.end_id 
inner join
    city city4_ 
        on address3_.cid_id=city4_.cid_id 
left outer join
    person person5_ 
        on addresspe0_.pes_id=person5_.pes_id cross 
join
    organization organization1_ 
inner join
    person person2_ 
        on organization1_.pes_id=person2_.pes_id 
where
    and organization1_.org_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is causing the cross join

```
newQuery().from(addressPerson,organization)
```

You need to move either `addressPerson` or `organization` to an inner or left join.